# BeautifulSoup concatenating words

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
>>> BeautifulSoup('<span>this is a</span>cat').text
u'this is acat'
>>> BeautifulSoup('Spelled f<b>o</b>etus in British English with extra "o"').text
u'Spelled foetus in British English with extra "o"'
```

Some parses between markup tags deserve spaces between them( like that `acat`). What is a good way to make sure that the parser puts spaces wherever it is meaningful? I am trying to convert emails to text.

Comment: There is probably no way to do this. That's a fault in the HTML. Only way to do this would to distinguish the differences between markup that need a space and markup that does not

Answer (score 6):

Edited based on comments:

BeautifulSoup has support for first example. All you have to do is

```
BeautifulSoup('<span>this is a</span>cat').get_text(" ")
```

It will join the text between two elements using space. It is documented [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: And it will do that to the second example as well. So, no, not a good solution.

Comment: @usr2564301, agree. I have corrected the response. However when I ran TerryA solution its output for second example is 'Spelled f o etus in British English with extra "o"' which is similar to mine solution. I tested it on python3.6, not sure if that has made any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I was wrong:

```
def grab(soup):
    return ' '.join(unicode(i.string) for i in soup.body.contents)
           # soup.body.contents contains a list of all the tags
           # [<span>this is a</span>, u'cat']
           # [<p>Spelled f<b>o</b>etus in British English with extra "o"</p>]

           # i.string gets the text of a tag, similar to .text, but if there are tags in the tag you want to get the .string of, it will return None.

           # unicode() is used to convert it from a bs4 type to a string type. Used to call ' '.join()
           # It's good to use unicode() instead of str():
           ## If you want to use a NavigableString outside of Beautiful Soup, 
           ## you should call unicode() on it to turn it into a normal 
           ## Python Unicode string. If you don’t, your string will carry around 
           ## a reference to the entire Beautiful Soup parse tree, even when 
           ## you’re done using Beautiful Soup. This is a big waste of memory.

           # Lastly, as .contents returns a list, we join it together.

soup1 = BeautifulSoup('<span>this is a</span>cat')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup('Spelled f<b>o</b>etus in British English with extra "o"')
soups = [soup1, soup2] # here we have a list of the soups
for i in soups:
    result = grab(i) # It will be either u'None', or the correct string with a space
    if result == 'None': # If the result had a tag in between (i.e, like your second example)
        print i.text
    else:
        print result # The result with a space.
```

Prints:

```
this is a cat
Spelled foetus in British English with extra "o"
```

Comment: sorry, I tried it only just now by putting into a file and the only line in grab gives a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'`. I am working on it right now:)

Comment: @aitchnyu Hmm, what was the sentence you were trying to do ;3?

Comment: your same script in a `.py` file, I have 3.2.1 version of BS. Its end of my workday here, will check it tomm. Sorry for not checking it earlier and doing this.

Comment: @aitchnyu That's fine. In my examples, I use version `4.1.3`. I'm about to go to sleep now anyways :)